# More than one instance of IsolatedStorageSettings?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, application-settings, isolatedstoragefile

I am looking at way to store data in Win Phone 8 using C#.

Firstly, is it possible to create more than one instance of IsolatedStorageSettings?

For example would the code below amount to two separate sets of settings:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
IsolatedStorageSettings settings2 = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

Secondly I looked into IsolatedStorageFiles but got an error on the code below. May be the example I'm using has skipped some steps.

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
```

Errors:

- 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile' does not contain a
  definition for 'GetStore'
- The name 'IsolatedStorageScope' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'IsolatedStorageScope' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article on MSDN [IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings) as it clearly state

> Gets an instance of IsolatedStorageSettings that contains the contents of the application's IsolatedStorageFile, scoped at the application level, or creates a new instance of IsolatedStorageSettings if one does not exist.

so it is not possible to create more then one instances of `IsolatedStorageSettings`.

For `IsolatedStorageFiles`, There is a pretty comprehensive example at the msdn page for dealing with it. [IsolatedStorageFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)